# Axios POST wrong timezone VueJs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, timezone

I have problem with axios. In my app i have input datetime-local. When I choose date and time I'm getting right time (if i choose 10:00, I'm getting 10:00) but when I'm calling function with axios.post, in request i have wrong time zone (axios post 9:00 instead 10:00)

This is my code:

**Input**

`<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="form-control-classesStart" v-model="newClasse.classesStart">`

**Function**

```
      this.newClasse.roomId = this.selectedItem.id
      this.axios.post(Linklist.apiClasses, this.newClasse)
      .then(response =>{
        console.log(response)
        this.$store.dispatch('loadClasses') // pobierz ponownie dane z bazy w celu odświeżenia
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Coś poszło nie tak: ', err)
      })
    },
```

[Screen from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wT92.png)

[You can see: 13:50 insted 14:50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUvc0.png)

Any ideas what I can do?

**EDIT:**

I have an idea, maybe I can store time in UTC timezone and change it with some function in front-end? It's good or bad idea?

Comment: Update your code with the part where you create the data object, probably you are creating the date with the default timezone and setting to the classesEnd/classesStart

Comment: Im using v-model, picked date and time has this form: "2021-03-19T14:50" so i don't have any info about timezone. How i can set timezone here? There is no way to set time zone using input type datetime-local. I thought that if I have a specific time in the variable, the same value will be sent in request to backend

Comment: Since you are getting back a string, before posting create a new Date(v-model-var).toLocaleString() and it will solve your problem.

Comment: So, this solution isn't working for me... When I create a new Date im getting null in axios request... Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what i said was to parse the string you get from date and save it, mdn has some guides into Date, check there, because you string format seems just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer might help you: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1548#issuecomment-548306666

TLDR;
Dates are converted to UTC by default in `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the axios calls JSON.stringify() for serialization date that converts date to a UTC date string. If your project has no UTC time requirements, you could just overrides the the Date's toJson() function.

Here is the toJson() overrideing with moment library:

```
import moment from 'moment'
Date.prototype.toJSON = function(){ return moment(this).format(); }
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Date()))
```